# Finding starting row number of a range name of Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

In an Excel worksheet, I have a range name "LOOPBACK_IP".
I want to programmatically find the starting row of this range name.

With Powershell, if I want to find the value of this range, I use (after assigning $ws variable a worksheet):

```
write-host $ws.Range("LOOPBACK_IP").Value2
```

But to find the location (i.e. row, column) of a range name, what do I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first row is the first element of $ws.Range("LOOPBACK_IP").Rows

... the property for the row number is .Row

For example in VBA, the following shows a msgbox with the number of each row

```
For Each rw In MyRange.Rows
    MsgBox rw.Row 
Next rw
```

Comment: Don't panic! Always have your copy of The Hitchickers Guide to the Galaxy at hand!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can call this the same way from Powershell, but the `ROW` function called on a range will return the starting row of the range. If you had a range `RangeName` that started at cell `C3`, `=ROW(RangeName)` would return `3`.

I think this may only work properly if your range is rectangular, but I can't confirm at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

`Names("LOOPBACK_IP").RefersToRange.Row` gives you the row; `.Column` gives you the (numeric) column.

You can also use `Names("LOOPBACK_IP").RefersTo` or `Names("LOOPBACK_IP").RefersToLocal` would give something like `=Sheet1!$D$9:$D$30`, if that might be useful - though I must admit I don't know what makes 'Local' any different.